# error TS2365: Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types '"("' and '")"'

Tags: typescript

```
function myFunc(id: string) {
  id = "(";
};

let id: string = ")";
if (id !== '(')
  throw "Expected '(' in prototype";

myFunc(id);

if (id !== ')')
  throw "Expected ')' in prototype";
```

If I do the change inline then I do not get the error below

```
error TS2365: Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types '"("' and '")"'.
```

The contents of the comparison dont matter. Any string a, basdasd, cqwe, etc. can be used in place of ( and )

Comment: can you describe what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Perhaps off-topic: be aware that the `id` argument inside `myFunc` is shadowing the `id` variable outside `myFunc`. As a result, `myFunc` doesn't actually change the value of the 'global' `id` variable, so calling it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: The error persists even after fixing it. I think it is a bug or limitations with TypeScript type narrowing and widening. The side effect on `id` defined in `myFunc` should widen `id` to `string`, but it's clearly not.

Comment: There is no side effect on `id` in `myFunc`. The `id` in `myFunc` is a local variable only. That is why typescript is complaining.

Comment: @Duncan I know that, was referring to my fix. I posted this issue to TS https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is type narrowing. After passing the first if statement, the type of `id` is narrowed to string literal ")" because otherwise the exception would have been thrown.

```
function myFunc(id: string) {
  id = "(";
};
// Note that this function does nothing, but it's not the issue here

let id: string = ")";

if (id !== '(')
  throw "Expected '(' in prototype";
// id is narrowed to "("

myFunc(id);

// now id and ')' does not have same type, hence the error
if (id !== ')')
  throw "Expected ')' in prototype";
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I define an instance/variable in which I would like to hold different kinds of strings? e.g. If I'm looping over tokens from an array while parsing?